# Why does the power operator in F# only work for floating point numbers?

Tags: f#, language-design

I have never seen a language have exponent or power operator only taking floating point numbers?

For example:

`2 ** 2` throws an error `The type 'int' does not support any operators named 'Pow'`

Are there valid reasons for this design decision?

Comment: +1, looking for some great answers :)

Comment: I'd agree that it seems a little odd that the only version is  `nonint ** nonint`

Comment: What other languages implement `**` for integers? All the ones I can think of just coerce to floats.

Comment: @Gabe: In Python "10**100" evaluates to a long integer. It doesn't coerce to floats. "10.**100" and "10**100." are evaluated as floats.

Answer (score 46):

`(**)` and `pown` are two different things. When you see `(**)`, you can think of the mathematical formula using logarithms. When you see `pown`, it's just a series of multiplications. I understand it can be surprising/confusing at first, because most other languages don't make such a difference (mainly because integers are often implicitly converted to floating point values). Even in maths, there a small difference: See the [Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation), the first definition works only for positive integer exponents.

As they are two different (but related) things, they have different signatures. Here is `(**)`:

```
^a -> ( ^b ->  ^a) when  ^a : (static member Pow :  ^a *  ^b ->  ^a)
```

And here is `pown`:

```
^a -> (int ->  ^a)
when  ^a : (static member get_One : ->  ^a) and
      ^a : (static member ( * ) :  ^a *  ^a ->  ^a) and
      ^a : (static member ( / ) :  ^a *  ^a ->  ^a)
```

If you create your own type, you only need to have your `One`, `(*)`, and `(/)` to get it work with `pown`. The library will do the loop for you (it's optimized, it's not the naive O(n)).

If you want to use the `(**)` operator on your type for non-integral values, you'll have to write the full logic (and it's not be the same algorithm as in `pown`).

I think it was a good design decision to separate the two concepts.

Comment: Excellent answer, I completely agree, except bigint implementing Pow seems to be an inconsistent choice. Perhaps the bigint specific optimizations possible were to compelling.

Comment: Documentation says "Return n^m for two big integers", but signature is "BigInteger * int32 -> BigInteger". I think there was a confusion somewhere.

Comment: Actually, BigInt in F# library implements Pow to make the type binary compatible with System.Numerics.BigInteger class from .NET 4.0.

Comment: I agree: (**) is a more mathematical definition of power. Besides, you can't have a default pow operator with the signature int -> int -> int because 2 ^ -2 = 0.25. Power operations must return a float by default.

Comment: What about the type decimal? Why doesn't it support the pow operator? :/
I need to raise decimal numbers to a fractional power (1/n) as part of financial calculation and am worried by the loss of precision that would be introduced by casting the numbers from decimal to float

Answer (score 9):

For integral powers, F# provides another operator: `pown`.  Also, as a side note, both `(**)` and `pown` are overloaded, so it's perfectly possible to use them with other types which provide appropriate members (a static `Pow` method in the case of `(**)`; `(*)` and `(/)` operators and a static `One` property in the case of `pown`).

I can't speak to why the F# team opted not to simulate a `Pow` member on `int`, but perhaps they didn't feel it was urgent since the `pown` operator could be used instead (and since it probably makes more sense to convert to float first in the case of big operands).

Comment: indeed, `**` has the signature `^a ->  ^b ->  ^a when  ^a : (static member Pow :  ^a *  ^b ->  ^a)`, so `3I ** 1000`, `3.0f ** 3.2f`, and `3.0 ** 3.2` are all valid.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is because it isn't very useful for integer types, even int64s. 2^26 only gives you ~1.84467441E19. So if you had two values X and Y both greater than say 19, then the power operator will result in an overflow.

I agree it is useful for small values, however it isn't generally useful for integer types.

Comment: -1, F# has arbitrary precision integers that don't easily overflow.

Comment: Just tried it in F# interactive: `> 2.0**26.0
;;
val it : float = 67108864.0`

Comment: @Gabe - `**` is "overloaded", just not on int and int64, see @kvb's answer.  it works fine with bigints like `3I ** 1000`.

Answer (score 2):

The language that F# is based on is OCaml which does not do operator overloading or automatic data coercion (they prefer explicit coercion).

Thus even adding doubles requires a different operator (+.). I'm not sure if this is where F# gets its strictness on it for sure but I am guessing it is.

In dynamic languages like Python or Scheme you would get automatic data coercion to a bigger data storage if the number was too big. For example you could have integers with integer exponents giving a big-integer for the result.

OCaml and F# have a spirit of extreme type safety.

Comment: C's `pow()` requires `double` and produces `double`, and works for other types only because of autocoercion.  (`fpow()` uses `float` instead.)  OCaml and F# don't autocoerce, so you're stuck with floating point.  Perhaps if someone had had a use for it there would have been an integer version.

Comment: F# supports overloaded operators (and in fact `(**)` is overloaded, but just doesn't support `int`s as arguments).

Comment: Yeah sorry I didn't mean F# didn't support overloaded operators I mean OCaml doesn't. I can see how its confusing.